# Delete a specific range of rows from table in sybase database

Tags: sql-server-2005, sybase

I need to delete specific range of rows  from table in sybase database.

For example , I have 10 rows. but I want to delete 5 to 7 row from my table.
how can we delete .

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM someTable
WHERE myPrimaryKey in ( 5, 6, 7 )
```

In other words: You cannot just tell the DBMS to delete "the 5th record" from the table. You will have to construct a `where` clause that matches exactly those rows you want deleted.

When you think about it, this makes sense, because the DBMS does not guarantee any internal order of the records in a table, that is, it has no intrinsic concept of what the n-th record is.

Answer (score 0):

By default a table has no predetermined order so you have to define the order to delete 5-7th rows. You can try to use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to define the order in the table to count rows. For instance if you have a primary key `ID` you can order by this column:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
 SELECT T.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as RowNum
        FROM T
)

DELETE FROM T1 WHERE RowNum between 5 and 7
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18872/1)</kbd>